# Algolia React Instantsearch Hits component not persisting state

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I'm playing around with Algolia React instant search and I've created a basic component:

```
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Button, Offcanvas } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useState } from "react";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";
import {
  InstantSearch,
  SearchBox,
  Hits,
  Highlight,
  RefinementList,
  Pagination,
  Configure,
} from "react-instantsearch";

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  "REDACTED",
  "REDACTED"
);

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="react_demo_01">
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow} className="me-2">
          Open
        </Button>
        <Hits hitComponent={Hit} />

        <Offcanvas show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
            <Offcanvas.Title>Offcanvas</Offcanvas.Title>
          </Offcanvas.Header>
          <Offcanvas.Body>
            <RefinementList attribute="brand" />
          </Offcanvas.Body>
        </Offcanvas>
      </InstantSearch>
    </>
  );
}

function Hit({ hit }) {
  return (
    <article>
      <img src={hit.image} alt={hit.name} />
      <p>{hit.categories[0]}</p>
      <h1>
        <Highlight attribute="name" hit={hit} />
      </h1>
      <p>${hit.price}</p>
    </article>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, whenever I click on the button, the offcanvas opens up, and I select a brand, I can see the Hits component update in the background behind the offcanvas backdrop but as soon as I close the offcanvas component then the Hits components gets reset. Why does this happen and how can I tell the Hits component to remember what I previously selected in the RefinemenList component inside the offcanvas component?

I'm using the following versions btw:

```
"dependencies": {
    "algoliasearch": "^4.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "instantsearch.css": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-instantsearch": "^7.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984020/algolia-store-refinementlist-value-when-close-modal) see  if u can get some inspiration

Comment: Hi were you able to make any progress

Comment: by the way if u are still working on this https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch/discussions/5871 . i can write a proper answer but the `future` is not released yet

Comment: @cmgchess yes, I'm using s different offcanvas/drawer component. Don't remember the name but let me know if you're interested and I'll post it here.

Comment: sure you can post your solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is when the Offcanvas is closed, the `<RefinementList>` is also unmounted from the UI. So the state captured in the `RefinementList` is lost and you will lose all the applied refinements.

Starting from [React-InstantSearch 7.2](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch/releases/tag/react-instantsearch-core%407.2.0) you can achieve this with the [`future`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/react/#widget-param-future) flag to preserve state when unmounting

[Related thread](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch/discussions/5871)

The docs have a separate section to solve this problem on [Persisting state on unmounts](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/show-and-hide-widgets/react/#persist-the-state-on-unmount) using a **Virtual Widget/Component**. (NB - using `future` is not updated in this doc guide yet)

Virtual Widgets here are for the sole purpose of persisting the state and they will not be rendered in the UI. So it would look like something like below. `useRefinementList()` used to persist the applied refinements

```js
function VirtualRefinementList(props) {
  useRefinementList(props);
  return null;
}
```

When initializing you need to set the `future` attribute of the InstantSearch to
[`{ preserveSharedStateOnUnmount: true }`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/react/#widget-param-preservesharedstateonunmount)

so something like

```html
  return (
    <>
      <InstantSearch
        searchClient={searchClient}
        indexName={indexName}
        future={{
          preserveSharedStateOnUnmount: true
        }}
      >
        <VirtualRefinementList attribute="brand" />
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow} className="me-2">
          Open
        </Button>

        <Offcanvas show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
            <Offcanvas.Title>Offcanvas</Offcanvas.Title>
          </Offcanvas.Header>
          <Offcanvas.Body>
            <RefinementList attribute="brand" />
          </Offcanvas.Body>
        </Offcanvas>
        <Hits hitComponent={Hit} />
      </InstantSearch>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is a working demo
[image: Edit unmount refinementlist (forked) correct?]

Comment: Thanks. I don't remember the future flag while reading the docs. I might need to revisit the docs in the future. Currently I got it working with a different offcanvas/drawer component that I think has a "unmount" prop you can specify (set to false) so that it doesn't unmount when you close the offcanvas/drawer component.

Comment: @PussInBoots future flag is a new one. available after v 7.2 . the docs are not yet updated :) . had a discussion with the algolia engineers [here](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch/discussions/5871)

Comment: @PussInBoots sure if the library provides an option for hiding instead of unmounting that is also a valid solution as discussed [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/show-and-hide-widgets/react/#keep-the-widget-mounted-but-hidden)